# How to flatten delimited strings in a list-column of a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with one list-column, say:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"pairs": [["A|B", "B|C", "C|D", "D|F"], ["A|D", "D|F", "F|G", "G|D"], ["C|D", "D|X"]]})
```

The lists in the `pairs` column always contain consecutive pairs, where the 2 elements of the pairs are separated by a `|`. I want to kind of "flatten" the lists in these columns, by instead of storing the pairs, now storing the elements of the pairs in the same order. So the desired DataFrame looks like:

```
elements
[A, B, C, D, F]
[A, D, F, G, D]
[C, D, X]
```

(Edited: I also would like to have elements occur multiple times in a resulting list, like `D` in the second row)

This looks so simple and I can't believe there wouldn't be an efficient solution to this, but so far I have failed to find any python method that could help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use set-comprehension:

```py
df["elements"] = df["pairs"].apply(
    lambda x: {ww for w in x for ww in w.split("|")}
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                  pairs         elements
0  [A|B, B|C, C|D, D|F]  {B, C, D, A, F}
1       [A|D, D|F, F|G]     {G, D, F, A}
2            [C|D, D|X]        {X, C, D}
```

---

If you want lists:

```py
df["elements"] = df["pairs"].apply(
    lambda x: list({ww for w in x for ww in w.split("|")})
)
print(df)
```

```
                  pairs         elements
0  [A|B, B|C, C|D, D|F]  [D, F, A, C, B]
1       [A|D, D|F, F|G]     [G, D, A, F]
2            [C|D, D|X]        [X, D, C]
```

---

EDIT: To mantain order:

```py
def fn(x):
    seen = set()
    out = []
    for v in x:
        for w in v.split("|"):
            if not w in seen:
                seen.add(w)
                out.append(w)
    return out


df["elements"] = df["pairs"].apply(fn)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                  pairs         elements
0  [A|B, B|C, C|D, D|F]  [A, B, C, D, F]
1  [A|D, D|F, F|G, G|D]     [A, D, F, G]
2            [C|D, D|X]        [C, D, X]
```

---

EDIT: To keep multiple elements + order:

```py
from itertools import groupby, chain

def fn(x):
    return [v for v, _ in groupby(chain.from_iterable(v.split("|") for v in x))]

df["elements"] = df["pairs"].apply(fn)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                  pairs         elements
0  [A|B, B|C, C|D, D|F]  [A, B, C, D, F]
1  [A|D, D|F, F|G, G|D]  [A, D, F, G, D]
2            [C|D, D|X]        [C, D, X]
```

Comment: Would this work if a pair would occur multiple times in the list? So if we for example have [A|B, B|C, C|D, D|C], would this give me [A, B, C, D, C]?

Comment: your answer does not maintain the order of the elements in the pairs, which is very important. do you have a solution for that?

Comment: @Peter I've edited my answer to maintain the order.

Comment: @Peter I've also add a solution to keep multiple elements in the result.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest would be a double explode with groupby+unique:

```
df['pairs'].explode().str.split("|").explode().groupby(level=0).unique()
```

---

```
0    [A, B, C, D, F]
1       [A, D, F, G]
2          [C, D, X]
Name: pairs, dtype: object
```

Assign this back:

```
df['elements'] = df['pairs'].explode().str.split("|").explode().groupby(level=0).unique()
```

EDIT:

For considering only consecutive duplicates, use:

```
s = df['pairs'].explode().str.split("|").explode()
out = s[s.ne(s.shift())].groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

Comment: Would this work if a pair would occur multiple times in the list? So if we for example have [A|B, B|C, C|D, D|C], would this give me [A, B, C, D, C]?

Comment: @Peter Updated my answer addressing your comment

Comment: I'm sorry for being sluggish and didn't mention that specifically. If you could help me with a solution that also works for this case I will accept your answer

Comment: @Peter Please see the EDIT section. I have now updated based on your comment

Comment: Thanks for your edit! I only takes a massive amount of time to run, but I'm going to check if it works